# react-click event has empty event.target

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I get the target of the onClick event `div.id` inside the function `showChildren`?

Desired result:

```
div.id
```

Actual result:

```
<react></react>
```

Relevant Razor

```
  iterateNavigationObject: function(item) {

    var titleStyle = {
      'backgroundColor': 'grey'
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li style={titleStyle}>
            <div id="asdf" onClick={this.showChildren}>{item.text}</div>//I want the id of this element
              <ul>
                {item.items.map(this.iterateNavigationSubitems, this)}
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  },

  showChildren: function(){
    console.log(event.type);//OUTPUT:  'react-click'
    console.log(event.target);//OUTPUT:  <react></react>
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your click handler signature

```
showChildren: function(event) {
  console.log(event.type);//OUTPUT:  'react-click'
  console.log(event.target);//OUTPUT:  <react></react>
},
```

Explanation:
you might expect this to work from vanilla JS. Internet Explorer provides a global object window.event, which references the last event. And before IE9 there are no arguments in the handler. This applies to IE only (maybe other browsers as well). React uses it's own synthetic events, thus don't expect this to work. React passes `event` as first argument to all event listeners.

Regardless, you should not rely on this in React, nor vanilla JS. Always accept `event` as function argument.

**Edit**
To pass ID, use higher order function, which returns actual event listener.  Update call to this

```
<div onClick={this.showChildren("asdf")}>{item.text}</div>
```

Then, update listener to accept ID. You can disregard previous answer in this solution.

```
showChildren(id) {
  return () => {
    console.log(id);
  }
}
```